# Get an array of specific added children

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, loops, children

I'm using the following array to add children to the stage:

```
for(var i=0;i<6;i++) {
    var aCherry=new cCherry()
    aCherry.y=10
    aCherry.x=10+100*i
    stage.addChild(aCherry)
}
```

Now I want to modify each cherry based on another array. Something like this:

```
var cherryLetter:Array=[1,0,0,0,0,0]
    for(i=0;i<6;++) {
        if(cherryLetter[i]) stage.getChildByName("aCherry")[i].y+=90
    }
```

Clearly `stage.getChildByName("aCherry")[i]` isn't correct, but coming from JavaScript this makes the most sense to me and should accurately portray what I'm trying to achieve for you guys reading this. So, how would I actually do this? This being getting an array of children added to the stage under a certain name **or** class (so an array of cCherry would work too, if necessary), then using them in a way similar to the above loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my recommendation for how the code might look, based on the desire to use getChildByName() to find the instances of your cCherry class. Please note that I've changed the class name to Cherry in the example (which I recommend, since capitalizing class names is AS3 convention). Also, it's good practice to end statements with semi-colons. While it's usually optional, there are cases where omitting the semi-colon can produce very difficult to track down runtime bugs, so I recommend getting int he habit of using them. I also recommend including type in all your variable declarations, as shown with var aCherry:Cherry, for example.

```
var i:int;
for(i=0; i<6; ++i)
{
    var aCherry:Cherry=new Cherry(); // Note, it's my recommendation that you rename cCherry class to Cherry (convention)
    aCherry.y=10;
    aCherry.x=10+100*i;
    aCherry.name = "aCherry" + String(i); // String() cast for clarity only, not necessary
    stage.addChild(aCherry);
}
```

and

```
var cherryLetter:Array=[1,0,0,0,0,0];
for(i=0; i<6; ++i)
{
    var cherry:Cherry = stage.getChildByName("aCherry" + String(i)) as Cherry;
    if(cherry && cherryLetter[i]) cherry.y += 90;
}
```

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to assign them names? Isn't it possible to just get an array based on their class name?

Comment: If you don't assign your code-generated instances names, they will have default names like "instance1", "instance2" etc. There is no built-in way to get an array of all children of a given class, though there is nothing to stop you from writing a function that loops over all children and checks their type with "is" and returns an array of all children of a type. Obviously, if there are children of other types, this would be less efficient than naming them or saving an array of references to them at creation time, but unless there are hundreds of children, this is probably negligible.

Comment: +1 for an array of references. @Anonymous during the initial loop just push each created cherry into an array.

Comment: @Chris- Yeah, I probably shouldn't have buried that suggestion in a follow-up comment, because that is the only approach I would use personally. Maintaining an array of references to the cherries is cheap memory-wise, and array look-up is much faster than searching for children by name.